# スクリプト内でsudo hogeしようとするとPermission deniedで拒否される

Tags: macos, bash

tcpdumpを実施するシェルを書いたところ、Permission deniedで拒否されました。

```
#!/bin/bash -v
TEST_DIR="/Users/"
sudo tcpdump -Ini en0 -w ${TEST_DIR}/test1.pcap -W1 -G40 &
pid=$!

tcpdump: /Users/test1.pcap: Permission denied
```

事前に

```
sudo chmod 644 /dev/bpf*
```

も実行してあり

```
visudo
UserHoge ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

ともしてあります。

Comment: `sudo tcpdump -Ini en0 -w ${TEST_DIR}/test1.pcap -W1 -G40 -Z root` とするとどうなりますか？(`-Z root` を追加)

Comment: ありがとうございます。エラー無く実行が終わりました。

Comment: 了解です。それでは hayaMAX さんの方で回答をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo tcpdump -Ini en0 -w ${TEST_DIR}/test1.pcap -W1 -G40 -Z root
```

-Z オプションで書き込み権限を指定する。root もしくは sudo できるユーザを指定することで、エラー無く実行が出来ました。